# Sending data from AsyncTask in MainActivity to Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have been looking for the solution the whole day. But no solutions worked.

I have `AsyncTask` in my `MainActiviy`. In the `MainActivity` I have two fragments in a `ViewPager`.

I want to send JSON String from MainActivity's AsyncTask to both the Fragments.

The problem comes when I try to receive the String in fragments.

I have tried it in `OnActivityCreated` and `OnCreatView`.

The solutions I have tried are:

**Receiving through bundle arguments** -

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
result = bundle.getString("json");
result = getArguments().getString("json");
```

**Receiving through a function which returns a global variable (result)** -

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
result = activity.getMyData();
```

I have also tried to implement Communicator but I don't have tag or ID to link to my fragments in activity_main.xml.

Comment: What does the AsyncTask do and when? Is it executed before the fragments are created?

Comment: I have tried executing it both ways, before and after creating the fragment. AsyncTask get json value from a link. Then passes them to fragments .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried almost all possible solutions found online in last 6-7 days.  After a long research and tries I was able to solve my problem myself. (Strange didn't get much response here).

I used `List<Fragment>` and created fragments as `fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();`. And I added the fragments after receiving result from `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute()` and passed my string argument in a bundle through this method

```
public static Fragment instantiate (Context context, String fname, Bundle args)
```

And then I received arguments inside both the fragments through `getArguments()` in `onCreateView` method.

I does what I needed to do. Thanks for the answers and I hope this answer helps someone.

I realized, the problem was in, **when** to receive and access data passed from MainActivity whether it was from an interface method or a public method inside fragments which are called from an object of the same fragment from MainActivity. All of those solutions were throwing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deliver a callback, when the AsyncTask is finished.

```
public interface TaskListener{
    public void onResultAvailable(Result result);
}

private MyTask extends AsyncTask{
    private List<TaskListener> myListeners = new ArrayList<TaskListener>();

    public void addListener(TaskLister tl){
        myListeners.add(tl);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result){
        super.onPostExecute(result).
        for(TaskListener tl : myListeners){
            tl.onResultAvailable(result);
        }
        myListeners.clear();
    }
}
```

Your fragments and/or the main activity can implement the TaskListener interface and act accordingly.

**EDIT:**
The fragment implementation could contain the following code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TaskListener{

    @Override
    public void onResultAvailable(Result result){
        String jsonContent = result.toString();
        //do something with the result from the async task
    }
}
```

Now there is a frament, that can do something with the AsyncTask result, but it must also "subscribe" to the AsyncTask. Therefore, you can add the fragment as listener to the task before executing it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Something{

    public void onStart(){
        MyFragment fragment = findFragment();

        MyTask task = createTask();
        task.addListener(fragment);

        execute(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work like communicator interface? I have never seen or used this. 

Can you please be a little more descriptive? I am a beginner.  Do I need to call its function from fragment after putting it in MainActivity?

Comment: This is not a class or component, that is part of the android sdk. I used a very common software design pattern: [observer]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern . I'll get into more detail in the example...

Comment: I have started to understand now this. But I don't understand what you are doing in onStart() of MainActivity.

Comment: I don't know, at which point in the MainActivity's lifecycle the AsyncTask is started. I guessed, that this happens during onStart(), so I've put the task creation and execution there. The method findFragment() is just a placeholder, where you call the fragment from your view. The execute() method is a placeholder, for you to start the task execution. It was meant like pseudo code, where you do the actual implementation in the way, that you like. the important line of code is task.addListener(fragment);

Comment: Yes I got you now. Now one problem remain for implementing this. How do I find the fragment? As I mentioned I don't have any <fragment> tag in activity_main because I am implementing it through ViewPage and FragmentStatePagerAdapter class. Also I have two fragments layouts. Thanks for your help. I know I am asking a lot.

Comment: The MainActivity has a method getFragmentManager() and (for support of older device versions) getSupportFragmentManager(). Via the FragmentManager you have access to your fragments and control their activation and visibility states. Use [getFragment(), findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059699/sending-data-from-asynctask-in-mainactivity-to-fragment/26060197?noredirect=1#comment40848199_26060197). Insert a new fragment with putFragment() , or via [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).